# How to check if product is on sale (special price) in magento 2

Tags: magento2

products with special price, I need to display discount percentage.

```
$_savePercent = 100 - round(($finalPriceAmt / $regular_price) * 100);
```

If product in sale then and then this will calculate.
Anyone got any idea how to do it?
[image]

Comment: so you want if your main price is 185 and special price 148 then you need to show percentage as well on product detail page?

Comment: Did you get a solution ?

Comment: I have added solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php 
$SpecialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();

if($SpecialPrice){
    $regular_price = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
    $finalPriceAmt = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getValue();

    if($finalPriceAmt > 0 && $regular_price > 0){
        $_savePercent = 100 - round(($finalPriceAmt / $regular_price) * 100);
        if($_savePercent > 0){  ?>  
            <div class="price">
                <ul>
                    <li class="old_price">$<?php echo number_format($regular_price, 2); ?></li>
                    <li class="discount"><?php echo $_savePercent; ?>% off</li>
                    <li class="current_price">$<?php echo number_format($finalPriceAmt, 2); ?></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
<?php } } } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code and modify it according to your requirement.
Here I have rewritten the template file in my custom module.
You can rewrite it in your custom theme as well.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="final_price" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox</item>
                    <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Anshu_Custom::product/price/final_price.phtml</item>
                </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml**

```
<?php
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\RegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $priceModel */
$priceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');

/** ex: \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('final_price');
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
$schema = ($block->getZone() == 'item_view') ? true : false;
?>
<?php if ($block->hasSpecialPrice()): ?>
    <span class="special-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Special Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'schema' => $schema
        ]); ?>
    </span>
    <span>
    <?php 
    $item = $block->getSaleableItem();
    $_savePercent = 100 - round(((float)$item->getFinalPrice() / (float)$item->getPrice()) * 100); 
    echo $_savePercent . '% off';
    ?>
    </span>
    <span class="old-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($priceModel->getAmount(), [
            'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
            'price_type'        => 'oldPrice',
            'include_container' => true,
            'skip_adjustments'  => true
        ]); ?>
    </span>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($finalPriceModel->getAmount(), [
        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-' . $idSuffix),
        'price_type'        => 'finalPrice',
        'include_container' => true,
        'schema' => $schema
    ]); ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($block->showMinimalPrice()): ?>
    <?php if ($block->getUseLinkForAsLowAs()):?>
        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getSaleableItem()->getProductUrl() ?>" class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </a>
    <?php else:?>
        <span class="minimal-price-link">
            <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->renderAmountMinimal() ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: this piece of code will work only simple product type. Not suitable for configurable product type